# Counting date as user id

Tags: php

I am creating a ticketing system, using the date as my UID but it has +numbers to count, at first it's working, but now no error is appearing, what to remove and what to add in this code? Feel free to correct

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
ob_start();
$dbhost = '192.168.0.9';
$dbuser = 'dsc';
$dbpass = 'csd';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('ERROR CONNECTING TO MY
SQL');

$dbname = 'dbtips';
mysql_select_db($dbname);

if(isset($_POST['ok']))
{
                $id=$_POST['id'];
                $title=$_POST['newstitle'];
                $status=$_POST['newsstatus'];
                $street=$_POST['newsstreet'];
                $content=$_POST['newscontent'];
                $date=date("y-m-d");
                $udate=date("Y-m-d");
        $newslink=str_replace(" ","-",$id);     

        $ticket=mysql_query("select count(date) as ticketcount from tblnews where date='$date'",$conn);
        if($data=mysql_fetch_array($ticket))
        {
        $ticketcount=$data['ticketcount'];

        if($ticketcount==0)
        {
mysql_query("insert into tblnews(title,street,status,content,date,udate) values('$title','$street','$status','$content','$date','$udate-001')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<script>alert('1st Ticket of the day!')</script>";
        header('Refresh:0;URL=file.php');
        }
        else if($ticketcount==1)
        {
mysql_query("insert into tblnews(title,street,status,content,date,udate) values('$title','$street','$status','$content','$date','$udate-001')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<script>alert('2nd Ticket of the day!')</script>";
                header('Refresh:0;URL=file.php');       
        }

else
{
        header("Refresh: 0;url=file_table.php?n=".$id);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov its editted now, please check. Thanks

Comment: @darylcoronado I can't follow too

Comment: Your edit didn't explain me your problem:-)

Comment: What's my error in this code shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You line 45 and line 50 are missing the close tag

You should tidy up the coding for debugging easily

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();
    ob_start();

    $dbhost = '192.168.0.9';
    $dbuser = 'dsc';
    $dbpass = 'csd';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('ERROR CONNECTING TO MYSQL');

    $dbname = 'dbtips';
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    if(isset($_POST['ok']))
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $title = $_POST['newstitle'];
        $status = $_POST['newsstatus'];
        $street = $_POST['newsstreet'];
        $content = $_POST['newscontent'];
        $date = date("y-m-d");
        $udate = date("Y-m-d");
        $newslink = str_replace(" ","-",$id);     

        $ticket = mysql_query("select count(date) as ticketcount from tblnews where date='$date'",$conn);

        if($data = mysql_fetch_array($ticket))
        {
            $ticketcount = $data['ticketcount'];

            if($ticketcount == 0)
            {
                mysql_query("insert into tblnews(title,street,status,content,date,udate) values('$title','$street','$status','$content','$date','$udate-001')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<script>alert('1st Ticket of the day!')</script>";
                header('Refresh:0;URL=file.php');
            }
            else if($ticketcount==1)
            {
                mysql_query("insert into tblnews(title,street,status,content,date,udate) values('$title','$street','$status','$content','$date','$udate-001')",$conn) or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<script>alert('1st Ticket of the day!')</script>";
                header('Refresh:0;URL=file.php');       
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("Refresh: 0;url=file_table.php?n=".$id);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Always that open and close bracket. I'm using emacs as my edittor thanks again.